# Is there a way to display which files are open in each screen window?

Tags: gnu-screen

When doing Ctrl^A Shift-", displaying the list of windows like:

```
0 user@hostname:/path/to/directory
1 user@hostname:/path/to/directory
2 user@hostname:/path/to/other
```

Is there a way to display the files open in each of the windows?
Something like this:

```
0 user@hostname:/path/to/directory
      subdir/directory/file_number_1.txt
1 user@hostname:/path/to/directory
      subdir/directory/file_number_2.txt
2 user@hostname:/path/to/other
      subdir/other/file1.txt
      subdir/other/file2.txt
```

In the example, window #2 might have two files open if it's a split screen.

Comment: Each screen session is generally a shell.  You're asking if there's a way for `screen` to know (1) that the shell ran one or many possible editors and (2) for it to report the filename of the file that is open in that editor?

Comment: @AndyDalton - that is what I'm asking (though I didn't really think about it that way).

Comment: I know of no way, but someone else might have an idea for how to achieve that.

Comment: and of the multiple files which an editor in a particular window may have open, which one is the _visible_foreground_ edit session?

Comment: Read `man lsof`.